# New-MdbcQuery with datetime not returing the results

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query

I am trying to get the list of documents older than X date from my collection. However my query is not working for datetime.

I have a mongo atlas cluster with multiple databases and collections. I want to lookup for a specific collection and delete the documents under that collection that are older than X date and time. I could get the list of records and apply the filter on a powershell object but when I use the query while retrieving data, no results are returning.

```
$connstring = "mongodb+srv://User:pwd@clus56tg-a0ov.azure.mongodb.net"

Connect-mdbc -ConnectionString $connstring 
$global:Server = $Server
Write-Host "Server `$Server $($Server.Settings.Server)"

$allDatabases = ($Server.GetDatabaseNames()).Where{($_ -notmatch 'local') -and ($_ -notmatch 'admin') -and ($_ -notmatch 'config')}

$date = "9/16/2019 0:00:00 PM"
$query = New-MdbcQuery DateTime -LTE $date

#printing the query looks like this
#{ "DateTime" : { "$lte" : "9/16/2019 0:00:00 PM" } }

$settings = New-Object MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionSettings
$settings.GuidRepresentation = 2

foreach($dbname in $allDatabases)
{
    $database = $Server.GetDatabase($dbname)
    $collections = $database.GetCollection('consumerstate', $settings)
    $collections.Count() 

    foreach($coll in $collections)
    {
        Write-Output("Database Name: $coll.Database.Name, Collection Name: $coll.Name")
        ###This code works###
        $objs = Get-MdbcData -As PS -Collection $coll
        $objs.Where{$_.DateTime -le '9/16/2019 0:00:00 PM'}

        #or this works
         Get-MdbcData(New-MdbcQuery _id -EQ c33af1-acef-4g6a-ai05-aase56d5)
        ########

        ###This does not return any results###
        Get-MdbcData -As PS -Collection $coll -Query $query
#or this
        Get-MdbcData -Collection $coll -Query $query         
        return
    }
}
```

The record output looks like this.

```
Sendfeedlooppacket         {LatestRequestStatusTypeId, LatestRequestStatusDate, DisplayId, CId...}                                                                                                                                              
_id                        9f8a7-53vva-4xdr-b45c-a34hsd22e282                                                                                                                                                                                              
TenantId                   12sf3484c-e349-43a9-9951-80345sf268452                                                                                                                                                                                              
Consumer                   RequestService.MessageConsumers.RequestResponseConsumer                                                                                                                                            
DateTime                   9/19/2019 5:39:04 PM
```

I have gone through the tests(https://github.com/nightroman/Mdbc/blob/master/Tests/New-MdbcQuery.test.ps1)and noticed some with datetime and the interpreted query looked like this.
test { New-MdbcQuery Name -In $date } '{ "Name" : { "$in" : [ISODate("2011-11-11T00:00:00Z")] } }'

But in my case the date is not wrapped around ISODate.

Answer (score 0):

What I was missing is casting the datatype in the query.

$date = "9/16/2019 0:00:00 PM"
$query = New-MdbcQuery DateTime -LTE ([datetime]$date).

I need to do the same for guid and other datatypes.

Thanks to @nightroman for his help.